# Big $O$, little $o$ Notation

Tags: notation, asymptotics

So I've gone through the typical undergraduate math sequence (two semesters of real analysis, two semesters of abstract algebra, some measure theory, but I haven't taken discrete math) and in various posts online, I keep on seeing things such as 
$$O(x^2) $$
which I've never encountered in my formal education. What in the world *does* the big $O$ notation mean, to someone who's completely new to the notation, so that I understand how to use it? (It seems to me like a way to write "some polynomial stuff.")

I've also encountered "little" $o$ notation in studying for actuarial exams.

Also, why do we care about $O$ and $o$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Big $O$ notation:

$f(n)=O(g(n))$:

$\exists \text{  constant } c>0 \text{ and } n_0 \geq 1 \text{ such that, for } n \geq n_0: \\ 0 \leq f(n) \leq c g(n)$

$$$$

Little $o$ notation:

$f(n)=o(g(n))$:

$\text{ if for each constant } c>0 \text{ there is } n_0 \geq 1 \text{ such that } \\ 0 \leq f(n) < c g(n) \ \forall n \geq n_0$

In other words $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0}$

Comment: This is almost the full meaning. In particular, if you see $n$, this probably *is* the meaning. The full meaning is very similar, except that we may be sending any parameter (discrete or continuous) to any limit, and often do not say what that limit is. Typically context makes this obvious, or else we say $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x \to L$ (for whatever $L$, often $L=0$). Also, you should probably have absolute values. No one writes this, but technically $(-1)^n = O(-1)$ is true.